# Find an equation of each plane tangent to $K$ which is parallel to the plane $x-y+z=1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Let $K$ be the cone given by $z=\sqrt {x^2+y^2}$

Find an equation of each plane tangent to $K$ which is parallel to the plane $x-y+z=1$

Sorry for not writing my ideas because I have No idea to solve this, honestly:( There are lots of such questions I need to solve. If somebody show me one of them 's solution, I try to solve others on my own. I wanna learn such type questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A normal vector to the plane $x-y+z=1$ is $\langle 1,-1,1\rangle$. At each point (other than $(0,0,0)$) on the cone a normal vector is $\langle -x, -y, z\rangle$. Try to find all points on the cone where these normal vectors are orthogonal, that is, where $-x + y + z = 0$.

Comment: Please can you write more clear? :(

Comment: Sorry by the way I mis-write. I need to show parallel

Comment: OK, find points on the cone where $\langle -x,-y,z\rangle$ points in the same direction as $\langle 1,-1,1 \rangle$.

Comment: $(-x/z, -y/z, 1)=(1,-1,1)$ then $x=-z$  $y=z$ then, $(-z)^2+z^2=2z^2$ i.e $2z^2=z^2$ so $z=0$ implies $x=y=0$

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: @B11b: Did you get the final answer?

Comment: I could not get. I wrote on my previous comment. Please help me. :( @BabakS.

Comment: @B11b: It seems you changed the body of the problem. Anyway, yes. We get the origin as you found. In fact $\nabla f|_{(x_0,y_0,z_0)}=(x_0,y_0,-z_0)$ and if we want the target plane be parallel to the given plane so we have $\frac{x_0}{1}=\frac{y_0}{-1}=\frac{z_0}{1}$. By putting them in the equation of the cone, we get the $(0,0,0)$. But this is not good as Umberto noted so it seems that we don't have any parallel planes here.

Answer (score 2):

***Hint:*** For a level set $f(x,y,z)=C$, we note 
$\nabla f=\left\langle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right\rangle$
is normal to the surface at $(x,y,z)$.  We can apply this to both the plane and your cone, which can be rewritten as $x^2+y^2-z^2=0$