# Please show me the question related to Continuously differentiable function & smallest value & minimizer

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Suppose that the function $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R $ is continuously differentiable. Define $K= \{ x \in \Bbb R^n \mid \|x\|\le1\}$

a) prove that there is a point $x$ in $K$ at which the function $f: K \to \Bbb R$ attains a smallest value

b) let's suppose that if $\mathbf{p}$ is any point in $\Bbb R^n$ of norm $1$

then $\langle D(f(\mathbf{p}), \mathbf{p}\rangle $ is bigger than $0$

Show that each minimizer $x$ in (a) has norm less than $1$

---

Honestly, I could not solve this question in any way.(so, please do not downvote b'cuz of writing No idea.) this is not homework. I tagged this as a homework such that many people can see my question. I have just been starting to study real anlysis on my own on my summer holiday. Nobody teachs me. Thus, I am asking here too much. Therefore, please can somebody show me the solution step by step. Thank you:)

Comment: For part b), what if $f=0$?

Comment: $Df(0)=0$ i think.. @wj32

Comment: $Df(p)$ is always zero, so how is $Df(p)p$ supposed to be bigger than $0$?

Comment: For this, I need to accept $p=\frac{Df(x)}{||Df(x)||}$ Is it? @wj32

Comment: Can you please solve these two part step by step below answer part? Please.. Thank you so so much :) @wj32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Part a:***

The simplest solution is to say that because $K$ is compact (and connected), its continuous image must be compact (and connected), which means that $f(K)$ must be (a) closed and bounded (interval), which means that $f$ attains both a minimum and maximum over $K$.

***Part b:***

Let $\mathbf p$ be any point on the edge of $K$, that is, any point whose norm is $1$. Note that $\langle Df(\mathbf p),-\mathbf p\rangle$, which gives the directional derivative at $\mathbf p$ in the direction of the origin, is negative.  This means that $f$ is deacreasing along the vector from $\mathbf p$ to the origin.  By the continuity of $Df$ and the mean value theorem, we may show that there exists some $\delta > 0$ so that $f((1-\delta)\mathbf p)<f(\mathbf p)$.  Therefore, no point $\mathbf p$ on the border of $K$ can be a minimizer of $f$.

Comment: Note that for part a the connection hypothesis is useless.

Comment: To clarify that statement for OP: it is sufficient to show that $f(K)$ is closed and bounded, since any such set in $\mathbb R$ is closed and bounded.  So yes, noting connectivity is pointless.

Comment: Thank you again to reply my comment and solve my question for days:) To learn this answer is important for me. This is not homework but perhaps will be an exam question  @Omnomnomnom

Comment: Well what don't you understand about my answer? Maybe I can explain it a little bit more thoroughly.  Do you understand my line of reasoning?  Do you understand the logical steps?  Do you understand what all the words mean?

Comment: No No I understand this answer. I dont understand previous one.

Comment: This answer is so clear:))

Comment: The previous one as in this question? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439766/find-an-equation-of-each-plane-tangent-to-k-which-is-parallel-rto-the-plane-x

Comment: No, I posted the same question yesterday. And you made a comment about its answer. That is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440897/directional-derivatives-and-smallest-value?noredirect=1#comment944962_440897 I dont understand this.

Comment: Oh, now I understand, sorry for the confusion. I'm glad you understand everything, and I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: Sorry, I dont have an enough spoken language. I have just academic language. so misunderstanding heppened. Okay, No problem!:))